# how to get child row elements after collapsing it in tree data in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

[image: Before collapsing document tree]

As mentioned in image How do i get **notes.txt** cell content at runtime after collapsing **document** tree like in following.

[image: After collapsing document tree]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i have tried to assign id but after collapsing child element ag-grid will remove the element from page even it was disappeared from inspect element.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.